# There is a new Selenium 4 version that does some things a fair bit differently than selenium 3, should get its own tag?

Tags: feature-request, tags, selenium

There is a new Selenium 4 version that does some things a fair bit differently than selenium 3 As A result it seems that it should get its own tag.

The changes include but are not limited to:

- New driver constructors
- New ways of setting up waits
- New ways of setting up and running distributed test systems (including for docker and vms)
- Changes to Actions
- W3C Standardization
- Relative-locators - for finding element relative to other nearby elements
- Changes to window/tab management
- Deprecation of "DesiredCapabilities" for base web browsers - replaced by an overhauled options api

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely it should. There is [selenium](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/selenium) which is for Selenium 1, and also [selenium2](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/selenium2) and [selenium3](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/selenium3) - no reason not to continue the trend which appears to be working. Let's just make sure we're diligent about properly tagging things tagged with [selenium](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/selenium) when they really mean 2, 3, or 4.